In a 48K Spectrum why are there 5 successive contended cycles in JR?
In a 48K Spectrum, the contention pattern for the JR instruction (see e.g. https://sinclair.wiki.zxnet.co.uk/wiki/Contended_memory) is:
pc:4, pc+1:3, pc+1:1, pc+1:1, pc+1:1, pc+1:1, pc+1:1

There is an intriguing pattern of five consecutive "pc+1:1". Other instructions exhibit similar behaviour, such as all repeated block instructions (LDIR and family). What's the technical reason for this? Why does it apply contention to every single T state of the last M cycle?
I ask because I don't see any signal that reaches the ULA (/MREQ, /RD, /WR...) as an obvious culprit. All of these are inactive during the last M cycle, which is where this effect occurs.

That's simple. First and second bus cycles are recognized by ULA (as either insn fetch cycle or just memory read cycle) and thus have only single place where ULA could pause them.
After those two bus cycles, the Z80 is doing literally nothing on the bus, while keeping PC+1 shown on the address bus. As the ULA now has no idea what will happen next on the bus, it takes some precautions as to introduce clocking pauses as if any "empty" cycle could be start of some access in the "near-cycle future".
This way of handling 'empty' intervals on the bus is probably coming from the way Z80 performs IO cycles (first clock period during IO cycle has no indication of intention by IORQ_n or MREQ_n going down, only an address), as well as the fact that the accesses to ULA's port $FE need contention as well. That and the fact that the designers had a shortage of resources in ULA probably resulted in that odd-looking behaviour.
